# Include jar but not dependencies in war

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

I am building my project using maven and every thing was working fine. 
Now I have added one new dependency in my pom and maven is including all the dependencies of new jar on war, I just want to include that new jar in my war and not its dependencies.

So for I have tried `excludes` in `maven-war-plugin`. In that case I have to add tons of exclude entries in pom. Is there any better way??

Comment: do you include this war to ear later?

Comment: No, we deploy war directly

Answer (score 0):

First thing there is no harm in having independent jars into your war. sometimes it required at the runtime.

I dont think there is another option for this. if there are multile jars exsists try to pickup specific one...

Try with scope as compile

Comment: Problem is it is resulting in version mismatch. We are using version 2.0.4 of some library and this new jar is using 1.6.1, now web-inf lib contains both jars and my application is failing because 1.6.1 jar is picked before 2.0.4 I only need client classes from new jar